# Does bitcoind accept batch RPC calls?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc, python

Am currently sending RPC calls to bitcoind in Python3 in series using JSON:

```
import json, requests

def pull(command, foo):
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    payload = json.dumps({"method": command, "params": [foo], "jsonrpc": "2.0"})
    response = requests.get(serverURL, headers=headers, data=payload)

    return(response.json()['result'])
```

Ex:

```
pull('getblock', BLOCKHASH)
```

and hope to improve call speeds by doing batch RPC calls.

Is this possible and how so?

Answer (score 10):

Yes, this is supported. As specified by JSON-RPC 2.0, you can send in an array of requests, and receive an array of solutions.